# Does XNA support OpenGL

Tags: opengl, xna

Eventually, when I've finished the game I'm writing, I'd like to port it to XNA. I'm using C++ and OpenGL at the moment. My question is simply this: does XNA support OpenGL (I can switch from C++ to XNA language if need be)?

Comment: Your anti-Microsoft attitude is ridiculous. Especially when you're talking about XNA and .NET/C# which are widely regarded as some of the best technology in their respective fields. You really need to come up with better criteria for choosing your platform besides "I hate Microsoft".

Comment: My apologies. I do tend to voice my opinions a little too hard (understatement?). I'll edit my OP and keep my personal opinions just that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [XnaTouch](http://xnatouch.codeplex.com/) implementation runs on iPhone and so uses OpenGL ES under the hood. It uses C# via the Mono project (specifically MonoTouch for the iPhone). This could conceivably be used as a base to port XNA to other platforms that don't support DirectX (eg: Mac, Linux).

(Note: in my experience the XnaTouch implementation is not very good.)

Obviously the Xbox 360 doesn't use OpenGL at all - it uses DirectX - you don't get an option about this.

And I don't even understand why you'd want to use XNA, but with OpenGL under the covers, on Windows when the existing XNA implementation works just fine.

Comment: I'm just a little wary of having to learn an entire new graphics library, but I guess I have no option. It's a shame XNA or XBox doesn't support OpenGL - it would make it much more attractive to smaller developers I reckon. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @JamWaffles Fortunately changing graphics libraries is like changing programming languages. The basic concepts are all the same - it's all just vertex buffers and index buffers and shaders and render states and so on. (Admittedly OpenGL lets you use things like immediate mode, which XNA doesn't support. But these things are so outdated and slow that you shouldn't be using them anyway.)

Comment: That's how I was doing all my OpenGL stuff until about 20 seconds ago when I read your post! I'll be using more vertex buffers and definitely shaders - they look so cool but I haven't managed to wrap my head around GLSL yet. From what I've read in this thread, it looks like a while before I port to XNA. Should get there eventually!

Answer (score 5):

No, not directly. XNA is built upon DirectX.

You can spin off a separate window, using a wrapper around OpenGL if you want however. You'll need to use a unofficial binding though, in order to do this. Then use XNA constructs within this. I've worked on a project like this and wouldn't reccommend it. There are two ways to use XNA. The by the book approach, which is too limited for most, or the other way. The 'other' way being not making use of the base game classes and handling your own game logic. With the second approach using another rendering method is too much work for no real pay off.

I'd recommend that for your current game the logic and graphics are separate. If you do decide to port at a later date, the transfer should be easier to convert from C++ to C#.

Also, XNA is not a language. It's a framework built using C#.

Comment: Bah! Crap. Oh well. Looks like XBox won't be getting any of my code, which is good I guess. Also, thanks for the extra info - the OpenGL implementation looks scary! As for XNA not being a language, I knew it used .NET but somehow forgot to mention that in my OP. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'd encourage you to check XNA out though. I used to be a hardcore C++ nut, but a few weeks with XNA and you'll love it. Plus C# is a joy to work with in comparison to C++. Doesn't help you at present, but worth playing with.

Comment: Good points. I'll definitely have a play around when I have a working C++/OpenGL implementation of my game (think years :-P)